# Passing Charachter in to Regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I would like to pass characters like A,B,C,D like this to a preg_match function in PHP.
Eg >

```
if (preg_match ("/^SEQRES.*\s$char\s.*/", $amino)) ;
```

I would like to pass A,B,C,D to $char and loop through the match.
please give me a solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the `{}` toolbar button. I've done it for you this time.

Comment: Should every of those 4 characters match, or only one? If many, should be combinations of those characters be allowed? Do you need to know which character(s) matched?

Comment: only one character to be placed at $char. Concatenation solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for a loop. Simply replace `$char` with  `"[A-D]";`. Since you have bounded it by spaces, it will match one single character in the class `[A-D]` between spaces .

```
if (preg_match ("/^SEQRES.*\s[A-D]\s.*/", $amino)) ;
```

You may also wish to use [`preg_match_all()`.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

Answer (score 2):

Just use string concatenation:

```
$re = "/^SEQRES.*\s" . $char . "\s.*/";
if (preg_match($re, $amino))
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_quote` if you are getting the character from user input:

```
$re = "/^SEQRES.*\s" . preg_quote($char) . "\s.*/";
```